# How do I display contacts when UITextField is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have tried multiple times to create a `UITextField` that when clicked should show the contacts available on the device and retrieve the phone number and display it in the textfield. However I have been unable to do that. The best that I could do is to use a button to receive and display the number on a textfield. This works! How do I do the same for when the `UITextField` is clicked?

I'm running it on Xcode 10

```
private let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTextFields()
        configureTapGesture()
        phonenumber.textContentType = .telephoneNumber

     }


    private func configureTextFields() {
        phonenumber.delegate = self

    }

    private func configureTapGesture(){
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SelfTestTimer.handleTap))
        viewcontact.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }

    @objc private func handleTap(){
        viewcontact.endEditing(true)

    }



    @IBAction func pbbbbb(_ sender: Any) {
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}
    extension SelfTestTimer: CNContactPickerDelegate {

        func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {


            let phoneNumberCount = contact.phoneNumbers.count

            guard phoneNumberCount > 0 else {
                dismiss(animated: true)

                return
            }

            if phoneNumberCount == 1 {
                setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[0].value.stringValue)

            }else{

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select one of the numbers", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

                for i in 0...phoneNumberCount-1 {
                    let phoneAction = UIAlertAction(title: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue, style: .default, handler: {
                        alert -> Void in
                        self.setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: contact.phoneNumbers[i].value.stringValue)
                    })
                    alertController.addAction(phoneAction)
                }
                let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
                    alert -> Void in

                })
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

                dismiss(animated: true)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        func setNumberFromContact(contactNumber: String) {


            var contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
            contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
            contactNumber = contactNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
            guard contactNumber.count >= 10 else {
                dismiss(animated: true) {
                    self.presentAlert(alertTitle: "", alertMessage: "A maximum of 10 contacts allowed per session", lastAction: nil)
                }
                return
            }
            phonenumber.text = String(contactNumber.suffix(10))

        }

        func contactPickerDidCancel(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController) {

        }




}

extension SelfTestTimer: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


}
```

I want it so that when the `UITextField` is clicked, the contacts will appear and when one contact is selected, the number should appear in the textfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method. Open the contacts controller in this method and return `false`, no need to add a gesture recogniser.